# Export as CSV on Powershell with output file name as timestamp

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to export a script as a timestamped csv and this isn't an existing csv. I'm running a command to get data and I need the output to be exported as a timestamp (month, day, year, hour, minute). I tried from others but it seems they're doing it from an already existing csv and changing the name to timestamp. Here's that part of my script:

```
Export-Csv -Path "C:\Parts\PartOne\Automation\$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I need it to grab the current date of when the command was run and output.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: the command I have isn't working. so what needs to be changed for it to output as a timestamp?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I just tested it and it works just as expected. Or I did get you wrong. You wanted to be time stamp as the file name, right?

Comment: Yes, time stamp as the file name, and I need it in that directory that's in the command

Comment: Yes - that's what this code does. Do you get an error when you run your code? If yes please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the content to be exported and then export to CSV?

Ex.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path "C:\PathToYourFile"

$content | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Parts\PartOne\Automation\$(Get-Date -UFormat `'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').csv" -NoTypeInformation`
```

Comment: I doubt that this provides any meaningful data. ;-)  ... and there are two unnecessary backticks in your code